# How to remove border from jqplot charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, jqplot

It would be helpful if someone could tell me how to remove the top and right border from jqplot charts. I have tried the grid properties but it is an all or null option and individual border value cant be controlled. Is there any other property which can set the value for individual border line.

Comment: Hello, there isn't an option for that.

Comment: cant we edit the css files or js files and bring in that option?

Comment: No, because the grid is being rendered in HTML5 canvas and no CSS is there..

Comment: grid:{borderWidth:0, shadow:false}

Answer (score 1):

For bar charts and line charts, use the following options:

```
grid: {
   drawGridlines: false,       
   background: 'transparent',   
   borderColor: 'transparent',  
   shadow: false            
}
```

For Donut charts, use :

```
grid: {
  borderWidth:0,
  shadow:false         
}
```